# jquery-ui position is not taking margin into account?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jquery.ui.position is not taking the margin values when positioning items?

I have this example, showing that there is no separation between left and right divs ...

http://jsbin.com/ebamom/3/edit

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give margin between two divs using one more Div. I have check this one and find space between two divs.

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  .recuadro {border:solid;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="height:200px;width:300px;" class="recuadro">
    CONTAINER
    <div id="left" style="height:150px;width:100px;margin:10px"  class="recuadro">LEFT</div>
    <div id="between" style="height:150px;width:1px;margin:10px"  class=""></div>
    <div id="right" style="height:100px;width:80px;margin:10px" class="recuadro">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
// Testeo de jquery.ui position
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#between").position({my:"left top",at:"right top",of:"#left"});
  $("#right").position({my:"left top",at:"right top",of:"#between"});

});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I want to know what is wrong whit my approach or if there is a bug in position, or if this is by design

Comment: If I want to force the margin, I can use offset (http://jsbin.com/ebamom/6/edit#javascript,html) and try some calculations with margins and positions ...

Comment: Hi, i think so here jquery position function will fit the div as per parameter. I think so it doesn't consider offset at a time of called position fucntion. There is nothing wrong in your approach or there is no bug.